# Why can't javac compile Java 1.5 code to run on Java 1.4 JVMs?

Tags: java, javac

Why can't the Java compiler compile Java 1.5 source code (with for-each loops for instance) to Java 1.4 bytecode?

I know that you can provide a `-target 1.4` switch, which tells the compiler to produce 1.4 compliant bytecode, but this requires `-source 1.4` as well.

```
$ javac -target 1.4 -source 1.5 Test.java
javac: source release 1.5 requires target release 1.5
```

I'm taking a course in compiler construction now, and as I understand it, compilers transform the source code into an intermediate representation anyway. Why can't such intermediate representation be output as 1.4 compliant bytecode? It sounds like an easy enough task, since, for each loops, varargs etc are basically just syntactic sugar!

(Note that I can see that API classes introduced in Java 1.5 obviously can't be referred to when executing on a 1.4 JVM. I'm still interested in the situation in which you stick to the 1.4 API.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Java 1.5 provides features that are simply not present in a 1.4 VM.

What should the compiler do if your source contains generics? Or an `enum` definition? What if it does autoboxing?

There are workarounds for all of these issues, but it's not the job of the Java compiler to implement workarounds. Instead you either need to port your source to a Pre-Java-5 level or use a tool such as [Retroweaver](http://retroweaver.sourceforge.net/) (there's a more modern replacement for that out there, but I keep forgetting its name, since luckily I no longer need to use it).

Also note that Java 1.5 code that doesn't use any of the new features (`enum`, auto-boxing, generics) most likely *can* be compiled using `-source 1.4`.

Comment: To be pedantic, generic information is erased at compile-time in all versions, 1.5 and 1.6

Comment: Autoboxing can be dealt with entirely in the compiler - isn't it already? Enums are foiled by the lack of java.lang.Enum before 1.5.

Comment: @matt b: to be doubly pedantic: no, it's not. It's erased at runtime. The `.class` file *still* contains the generics information in many places (class definitions, field definitions, method signatures, ...). Only the runtime ignores it (after loading)

Comment: @Tom Anderson: Autoboxing can easily be replaced with [`Integer.valueOf(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)) (and similar methods). Except that this method only exists since 1.5. Replacing it with `new Integer(int)` could result subtle bugs in less-than-perfect code.

Comment: I'm just puzzled: We can compile for instance Scala and JRuby to Java 1.5 bytecode, but not Java 1.6 source code! It seems to me that the leap from Scala to 1.5 bytecode, would be light years longer than from Java 1.6 to 1.5 bytecode. (I was hoping for a more "fundamental" reason.)

Comment: @aioobe: Java 1.5 and Java 1.6 bytecode are identical. There has been no byte code related changes in Java 6. And the only compiler-level change was some handling of `@Override` (which was "broken" in Java 5, depending on how you look at it). The reason why `javac` doesn't allow these trivial "backports" is that Sun says "Java 6 code runs on Java 6. Java 5 code runs on Java 5 or 6. But Java 6 code *does not run* on Java 5." Having the compiler present a different view would be confusing.

Comment: @aioobe It could be done with a different mapping from Java source to Java bytecode. It's because Java has a kind of direct mapping the problem arises. Java bytecode fits very closely to Java 1.0 source.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer, "The reason why it doesn't work, is because Sun says it shouldn't work"?

Comment: @Joachim Sauer One change between 1.5 and 1.6 is that stack map/table thing to improve verification performance (not sure that it is actually in the modified spec).

Comment: @Tom Hawtin, Ok, so basically, a programmer which is "used to a direct Java -> bytecode mapping" should not get any nasty (performance?) surprises because his `enum` is actually compiled to a `class`?

Comment: @Tom: I didn't know that. @aioobe: yes, basically that. That's why projects like Retroweaver exist to let you do it anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that some enhancements in Java 1.5 did not involve the introduction of any new bytecodes or class file format changes. There are others like annotations and enums that did. Therefore arbitrary Java 1.5 source cannot be compiled to a valid Java 1.4 class. That being said there is a project named retroweaver that aims to transform Java 1.5 class files to Java 1.4 class files available at http://retroweaver.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: Interesting side-note: annotations can be stored in class files that can easily be read by a 1.4-era JVM. They are just attributes with a special value and the JVM ignores unknown attributes.